# Face yaw angle estimation from silhouette

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, face-recognition

I am trying to estimate the pose - only yaw angle - of a face by using the segmentation information. In short, an image of a face has been segmented into "hair", "skin" and "background" pixels. The groundtruth for these is available. The faces are roughly centered. An example of this is given [here](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/part_labels/).

[image]

Trying to have a regression from segmentation image to yaw angle rank (leftmost = 1 to rightmost = 500, say) over a training set 500 images.

I am basically wanting to throw around a few ideas here and get some feedback. (Hopefully this won't be shut down as "unconstructive").

- A ready estimate of yaw angle can be seen by how much of hair and skin pixels is in the left part of the image - some form of moments about the central axis of the image. Something of this sort was reported in this [paper](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/papers/unconstrained_face_workshop.pdf). But implementing it (basically a quadratic regression scheme using moments of skin pixels and hair pixels about the center vertical line of the image) is giving quite noisy results
- I used a Convolutional Neural Network architecture for a 2-class problem (face/non-face classification) trained with Left pose and Right pose images. The classification was pretty decent ~70% accuracy with only 250 training and 250 test samples. However, regression to a smoothly varying pose value again gives quite noisy results

Quite at wits end. Thinking of implementing some sort of histogram of 8-directional chain codes, akin to an HOG but for the segmentation image.... or maybe encode the boundary using Fourier Descriptors and train a Neural Network to learn the non-linear relationship between segmentation and pose.

Can I get some feedback/ideas on this problem? Its an independent study I am doing (had enough of my usual field - OCR and text detection).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can tell you why the moments about the centerline will never work: look at [this](http://photos.posh24.com/p/1580350/z/fun_pics/ashlee_simpson_rock_chic_gray.jpg) image, or [that](http://powerforwardinsports.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/reeva-steenkamp-la-fidanzata-di-oscar-pistorius.jpg?w=300) one, and you understand why all the examples in the paper you cite are people with short or symmetric hairstyles, and why its title begins with "Toward".

But, seriously, is this some kind of textbook or job interview question? As in "let's see how much good information we have and can throw away in exchange for nothing, and still come up with some kind of half-baked quasi-answer by throwing oogles of computing power at it?". 
If this is a real world application, I'd recommend taking a second hard look at the imagery you have available, and figuring out what other features you can pull out of it that are related to face pose.

Comment: fair point. facial landmark detection and pose estimation from there is quite well known. still, trying out stuff before shifting to that